# .htaccess: What's the difference between "RewriteRule ^ -" and "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1"?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I cannot for the life of me figure out the difference between these two items, but even though in my current use, they both resolve to the ***identical*** URL, the **first** one is resolving successfully, but the **second** one gives a 403 error.

```
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [S=1]
```

Assuming they resolve to the same URL, what is the difference between these two?

(According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ , they both resolve to the exact same URL.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [S=1]
```

This rule will cause a redirect loop because it just redirecting to itself without any condition or pattern match. Even if there is no `R` flag in this rule but due to use of absolute URL in target a `R=302` will be sent back to client.

---

```
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]
```

This rule means **do nothing (no action)** and skip one rule below this.

Comment: I WANT to do nothing. You're saying the `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` won't do nothing, but will instead trigger a 302 redirect and not continue down the .htaccess? Could that be why `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` is returning me a 403 error?

Comment: 403 is most likely caused by another directive in your .htaccess or server config but right way of do nothing is `RewriteRule ^ -`

Comment: `403 is most likely caused by another directive in your .htaccess`. I'm sure it is, though I can't find it. However, the part that's confusing me is that in my current usecase, `^ -` and `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` output the *exact* same URL, but one of them triggers a 403 and one doesn't.

Comment: ...If I understand what you've said correctly, `^ -` is handled by my index.php, but `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` is probably getting a 302 redirect *instead* of being handled by index.php, and that's why even though they have the exact same URL, they don't act the same. Does that make sense, or am I completely off base?

Comment: Yes that completely makes sense, you have explained it very well